# How to choose k points, accoriding to minimum energy or minimum change in energy?

Tags: quantum-espresso

[image]I have converged k points and i have found curve like this, which k points should i use? 12*12*12 or 3*3*3 [image: K points vs energy]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Minimum change on energy (energy convergence or energy plateau). But keep in mind that those k points are only for the threshold used.

Answer (score 1):

You do not choose the ${\bf k}$-points by minimum energy. What you actually want is to get the termodynamic limit, which corresponds to the infinite ${\bf k}$-point grid.

The convergence shown on the curves is quite typical. You should choose the number of ${\bf k}$-points such that going to larger grids does not change the total energy significantly.